# How to make logger.Information("Hello") when MinimumLogLevel : "Error" In Serilog C#

Tags: c#, logging, serilog, log-level

How I can do logger.Information() in method, If I have LogLevel:Error.

Here's my serilog configuration in appsettings.json :

```
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Error"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: ? If you want to log "information" messages, you need to set the logger level to "information". If you want to keep the level at "error", but still need to report a message, it needs to be "error" or worse.

Comment: But if I  want to log information only in one method? Can I do it?

Comment: Yes, but IMHO it could be code smell and you should then probably look for a better solution. See [the manual](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration) for "Override"-ing the logging levels of separate paths/namespaces.

Comment: Don`t know why, but overide doesn`t work with namespaces. In works well with "Microsoft". But when i try to override for "MyProject.Class" it doesn`t work

Comment: "MyProject. **Class**" doesn't sound like a namespace, but a class name. "MyProject" should work as namespace. You should probably put the class in a separate namespace...

Comment: Yes, I`ve done it. But desn`t work

Comment: Maybe you should give a [mcve]...

Comment: No, it is not possible to set the log level in a single method only. You can change the log level per environment. Like, have your local machine log info but log only errors in production or stage environment.